# How to run a drush command in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I need your help, I want to run this comman in my console:

drush vset uc_product_nodes_per_page 50

but then console show me this error:

Command variable-set needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run[error]
this command.
The drush command 'vset uc_product_nodes_per_page 50' could not be executed.                                                               [error]
Could not find a Drupal settings.php file at ./sites/default/settings.php.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Are you running the command in the Drupal root directory, i.e. in the same directory as you installed Drupal?

Comment: This error says it cannot find the settings.php file - you need to `cd` into the drupal directory (Document root) of your drupal install in order for it to read in a settings.php file.

Comment: Thanks for the answers the problem was that de site are a multi-site and i need specific the correct site: drush -l www.mysite.com vset ....